# Statistic analysis on EEG data - how to deal with it properly?

Tags: eeg, statistics, electrophysiology

Let's assume that I have a datasheet looking like that:

```
Patient Electrode  Task Theta power
1       1          1    0.5
1       2          1    0.8        
1       3          1    0.1
1       4          1    0.9
...
1       1          2    0.3
1       2          2    0.9        
1       3          2    0.4
1       4          2    0.3
...
2       1          1    0.2
2       2          1    0.7        
2       3          1    0.3
2       4          1    0.4
...
2       1          2    0.6
2       2          2    0.7        
2       3          2    0.8
2       4          2    0.8
...
3       1          1    0.0
3       2          1    0.3        
3       3          1    0.2
3       4          1    0.8
...
3       1          2    0.2
3       2          2    0.5        
3       3          2    0.1
3       4          2    0.9
```

I have for example 20 patients, each of the patient has 128 electrodes recorded from one experiment with 2 categories. So data for the patients (for example this theta power on each electrode) are INDEPENDENT, because the data are from different people, and from only one run of the experiment. But on the other hand the data regarding electrodes from each patient are DEPENDENT, all electrodes share a bit of common signal.

What kind of statistical tests we can use to check the difference in for example this theta power between the task no. 1 and no.2? How to take care of this dependancy/independancy in neuroscience data?

Comment: I will answer my own question then. I found interesting article on this topic. I encourage everyone who has the same problem to read that one ("[Statistical testing in electrophysiological studies](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1469-8986.2011.01320.x)", Eric Maris, Psychophysiology)